# Text attribute changed for NSTextFieldCell on selection

Tags: cocoa, nstextfieldcell, fieldeditor

I have a tableview on which selecting a column of a row will call overridden method

```
- (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)inCellFrame inView:(NSView *)inControlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject start:(NSInteger)selStart length:(NSInteger)selLength {
  // here do some text positioning
         [super selectWithFrame:inCellFrame inView:inControlView editor:textObj delegate:anObject start:selStart length:selLength];
}
```

I also return field editor for the cell as under:

```
- (NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)inControlView {
   MYTextView* fieldEditor = [[[MYTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect] autorelease];
   return fieldEditor;
}
```

When the cell is selected the text within the cell changes its attribute. Like, the font size, font face, font style, etc changes accordingly, seems I have no control over it when the text is in selection mode. I do not want to change the font properties thereof even after selection How can i avoid this changes in text attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `-[super selectWithFrame:...]` method, changes to the text properties will be reflected. The solution is below:

```
- (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)inCellFrame
                 inView:(NSView *)inControlView
                 editor:(NSText *)textObj
               delegate:(id)anObject
                  start:(NSInteger)selStart
                 length:(NSInteger)selLength {
    // here do some text positioning

    [super selectWithFrame:inCellFrame
                    inView:inControlView
                    editor:textObj
                  delegate:anObject
                     start:selStart
                    length:selLength];

    NSMutableAttributedString* text = [textObj textStorage];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *alignmentStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] autorelease];
    [alignmentStyle setAlignment:NSLeftTextAlignment];

    NSDictionary* attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [attributes setValue:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSize]] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setValue:leftAlignmentStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];

    [text setAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
}
```